# How can i make my routes run properly on OVH and CakePHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, deployment, routes

I recently uploaded a website on OVH made with the CakePHP Framework.

The fact is that whenever I want to go on a prefixed route, like `/admin`, or a plugin route, like `/plugin_name`, it's just duplicate the route on the URL.

For example, I'm on `/admin/users/add`, I click on the link to go on the index admin ( `/admin` ), the URL will be `/admin/users/add/admin`. For every prefixed route.

I've put all my folders directly on `/www.`

Here are my different .htaccess files:

On the root:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ /app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Into the app folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    /webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) /webroot/$1    [L] 
</IfModule>
```

And into the webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Furthermore, That did the same with my CSS / JS declarations in the `<head>`, and I noticed that if I don't use the CakePHP HtmlHelper, it works. But I can't do that for all my links / forms.

Thanks.